# Following and replacing a marker in a real time video stream

Tags: c, image-processing, imagemagick, computer-vision, artoolkit

I want to create a program that can detect a marker in a real-time video stream an replace the marker with part of a picture i took before.
I am using ARtoolKit to recognize the marker.
First i will grab the video frame and save it as a jpg file then i will put the marker and let the video recognize the marker.
After the program recognize the marker but pressing a keyboard key i will call a function hode marker() who receive the jpg and the coordenates of the marker.
Maybe by using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) i will crop the image to feet the coordenates.
Then i will maybe create a opengl plane with the croped image has texture.
Need some help with how to code this.

Comment: Where are you stuck, what have you tried?

Comment: im using artoolkit i can show a vrml obj, but now i want to "hide the marker" and i dont know how to do it

Comment: I'm not familiar with artoolkit, but you probably need to do something similar to what is done here: http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/devstartup.htm#draw since it seems to use opengl for display I guess you'd draw your replacement image as a texture in some way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide marker in ArtoolKit or NyARToolKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230371/hide-marker-in-artoolkit-or-nyartoolkit)

Answer (score 2):

This is called [tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_tracking). There are many references on the Wikipedia page to get you started.

Comment: i know that a have to use tracking because i want to do it with artoolkit, but the problem is how to change the marker with a image.