# Hide marker in ArtoolKit (C)

Tags: c++, artoolkit

I am trying to hide the marker im artoolkit and in my research i found this code for alvar, it's a free AR toolkit made by a research technical center in finland.

This code helps hiding the marker but its in opencv, but i want to do the same in simpleVRML example.
Any help how can i change this code for the artoolkit example?

```
#include "CvTestbed.h"
#include "MarkerDetector.h"
#include "GlutViewer.h"
#include "Shared.h"
using namespace alvar;
using namespace std;

#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK // Needed to compile with Mingw?
#include <GL/gl.h>

const double margin = 1.0;
std::stringstream calibrationFilename;

// Own drawable for showing hide-texture in OpenGL
struct OwnDrawable : public Drawable {
unsigned char hidingtex[64*64*4];
virtual void Draw() {
    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrixd(gl_mat);

    glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    int tex=0;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,64,64,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,hidingtex);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3d(-margin,-margin,0);
        glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0);
        glVertex3d(-margin,margin,0);
        glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0);
        glVertex3d(margin,margin,0);
        glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0);
        glVertex3d(margin,-margin,0);
    glEnd();
    glPopAttrib();
    glPopMatrix();
    }
};

void videocallback(IplImage *image)
{
static bool init=true;
static const int marker_size=15;
static Camera cam;
static OwnDrawable d[32];
static IplImage *hide_texture;

bool flip_image = (image->origin?true:false);
if (flip_image) {
    cvFlip(image);
    image->origin = !image->origin;
}

static IplImage* bg_image = 0;
if(!bg_image) bg_image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(512, 512), 8, 3);
if(image->nChannels == 3)
{
    bg_image->origin = 0;
    cvResize(image, bg_image);
    GlutViewer::SetVideo(bg_image);
}

if (init) {
    init = false;
    cout<<"Loading calibration: "<<calibrationFilename.str();
    if (cam.SetCalib(calibrationFilename.str().c_str(), image->width, image->height)) {
        cout<<" [Ok]"<<endl;
    } else {
        cam.SetRes(image->width, image->height);
        cout<<" [Fail]"<<endl;
    }
    double p[16];
    cam.GetOpenglProjectionMatrix(p,image->width,image->height);
    GlutViewer::SetGlProjectionMatrix(p);
    hide_texture = CvTestbed::Instance().CreateImage("hide_texture", cvSize(64, 64), 8, 4);
}
static MarkerDetector<MarkerData> marker_detector;\
marker_detector.Detect(image, &cam, false, false);

GlutViewer::DrawableClear();
for (size_t i=0; i<marker_detector.markers->size(); i++) {
    if (i >= 32) break;
    GlutViewer::DrawableAdd(&(d[i]));
}
for (size_t i=0; i<marker_detector.markers->size(); i++) {
    if (i >= 32) break;

    // Note that we need to mirror both the y- and z-axis because:
    // - In OpenCV we have coordinates: x-right, y-down, z-ahead
    // - In OpenGL we have coordinates: x-right, y-up, z-backwards
    // TODO: Better  option might be to use OpenGL projection matrix that matches our OpenCV-approach
    Pose p = (*(marker_detector.markers))[i].pose;
    BuildHideTexture(image, hide_texture, &cam, d[i].gl_mat, PointDouble(-margin, -margin), PointDouble(margin, margin));
    //DrawTexture(image, hide_texture, &cam, d[i].gl_mat, PointDouble(-0.7, -0.7), PointDouble(0.7, 0.7));

    p.GetMatrixGL(d[i].gl_mat);
    for (int ii=0; ii<64*64; ii++) {
        d[i].hidingtex[ii*4+0] = hide_texture->imageData[ii*4+2];
        d[i].hidingtex[ii*4+1] = hide_texture->imageData[ii*4+1];
        d[i].hidingtex[ii*4+2] = hide_texture->imageData[ii*4+0];
        d[i].hidingtex[ii*4+3] = hide_texture->imageData[ii*4+3];
    }
}
if (flip_image) {
    cvFlip(image);
    image->origin = !image->origin;
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
try {
    // Output usage message
    std::string filename(argv[0]);
    filename = filename.substr(filename.find_last_of('\\') + 1);
    std::cout << "SampleMarkerHide" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Description:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  This is an example of how to detect 'MarkerData' markers, similarly" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  to 'SampleMarkerDetector', and hide them using the 'BuildHideTexture'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  and 'DrawTexture' classes." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Usage:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  " << filename << " [device]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    device    integer selecting device from enumeration list (default 0)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "              highgui capture devices are prefered" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Keyboard Shortcuts:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  q: quit" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Initialise GlutViewer and CvTestbed
    GlutViewer::Start(argc, argv, 640, 480, 15);
    CvTestbed::Instance().SetVideoCallback(videocallback);

    // Enumerate possible capture plugins
    CaptureFactory::CapturePluginVector plugins = CaptureFactory::instance()->enumeratePlugins();
    if (plugins.size() < 1) {
        std::cout << "Could not find any capture plugins." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Display capture plugins
    std::cout << "Available Plugins: ";
    outputEnumeratedPlugins(plugins);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Enumerate possible capture devices
    CaptureFactory::CaptureDeviceVector devices = CaptureFactory::instance()->enumerateDevices();
    if (devices.size() < 1) {
        std::cout << "Could not find any capture devices." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Check command line argument for which device to use
    int selectedDevice = defaultDevice(devices);
    if (argc > 1) {
        selectedDevice = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    if (selectedDevice >= (int)devices.size()) {
        selectedDevice = defaultDevice(devices);
    }

    // Display capture devices
    std::cout << "Enumerated Capture Devices:" << std::endl;
    outputEnumeratedDevices(devices, selectedDevice);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Create capture object from camera
    Capture *cap = CaptureFactory::instance()->createCapture(devices[selectedDevice]);
    std::string uniqueName = devices[selectedDevice].uniqueName();

    // Handle capture lifecycle and start video capture
    // Note that loadSettings/saveSettings are not supported by all plugins
    if (cap) {
        std::stringstream settingsFilename;
        settingsFilename << "camera_settings_" << uniqueName << ".xml";
        calibrationFilename << "camera_calibration_" << uniqueName << ".xml";

        cap->start();

        if (cap->loadSettings(settingsFilename.str())) {
            std::cout << "Loading settings: " << settingsFilename.str() << std::endl;
        }

        std::stringstream title;
        title << "SampleMarkerHide (" << cap->captureDevice().captureType() << ")";

        CvTestbed::Instance().StartVideo(cap, title.str().c_str());

        if (cap->saveSettings(settingsFilename.str())) {
            std::cout << "Saving settings: " << settingsFilename.str() << std::endl;
        }

        cap->stop();
        delete cap;
    }
    else if (CvTestbed::Instance().StartVideo(0, argv[0])) {
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Could not initialize the selected capture backend." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
}
catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Exception: unknown" << std::endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? BTW: the byte-swapping code looks suspect.

Comment: the problem its that i not good with computer vision and i dont now how to change this from opencv to the example in simplevrml example in artoolkit, they told with this example i can "hide" a marker in real time time, and i can to do that for a school project

Comment: This seems quite similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8576417/488657) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8230371/488657) that you've asked previously, however I can't tell if they are indeed identical. Is there any reason why they shouldn't be closed as duplicates of this (even though this is the newest question) ?

Comment: yep in the other questions i want to know also for java, bu not i just need help in C, and i didnt know how to insert the example code above i find, but even in the others questions i didnt get any good help